# Laplacian via $d^*d$ in spherical coordinates over the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm having problems to obtain the usual Laplacian on functions in Spherical coordinates over the round sphere $S^2$ using $d^*d$. My attempt:
Acting on 1-forms $d^*=-*d*$ so 
\begin{align}
d^*(\partial_\theta f d\theta +\partial_\varphi f d\varphi) &= -*d(\partial_\theta f \sin \theta d\varphi -\partial_\varphi f \sin \theta d\theta)\\
&= -*(\partial_{\theta\theta}f \sin \theta + \partial_\theta f \cos\theta)d\theta \wedge d\varphi - \partial_{\varphi \varphi } f \sin \theta d\varphi \wedge d\theta) \\
&= -\partial_{\theta \theta} f - \partial_\theta f \cos \theta \sin \theta -\partial_{\varphi \varphi} f
\end{align}
Thanks

Comment: Can you write down the parametrization? It is not clear how $g$ is written down in this coordinates.

Comment: @ArcticChar $g=d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \varphi^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of Hodge star operator, you fix an top form $\omega$ with unit length and define

$$\alpha \wedge *\beta = \langle \alpha, \beta\rangle \omega, \ \ \ \forall \alpha, \beta.$$

In our case, choose $\omega = \sin \theta d\theta \wedge d\varphi$. Since $\langle d\theta, d\varphi\rangle =0$ and

$$ d\varphi \wedge *d\varphi = \omega,\ \ \ d\varphi \wedge* d\varphi = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} \omega,$$

we have

$$*d\theta = \sin \theta d\varphi, \ \ \ *d\varphi = -\frac{1}{\sin \theta} d\theta.$$

Thus you'd get

$$\begin{split}-*d* df &= -* \left( \partial_\theta (f_\theta \sin\theta) d\theta \wedge d\varphi - \frac{f_{\varphi\varphi}}{\sin\theta} d\varphi \wedge d\theta\right)\\
&= -\left( \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \partial_\theta(f_\theta \sin\theta)+ \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} f_{\varphi\varphi} \right),
\end{split}$$

which is the same as the one given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplacesEquationSphericalCoordinates.html) (Note the difference of notations)

Comment: The second set of equations have a typo. You mean  $d\theta \wedge *d\theta = \omega$.